# Como recorrer celdas en un datagridView

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Mando llamar los datos de la DB hasta ahi todo correcto pero tengo que hacer unas formulas para que se calculen los valores, logre hacerlo con una sola fila pero quisiera saber si hay forma de hacerlo con todas las filas que hay

Si sirve de algo, este es el codigo que use para hacer los calculos habia leido que con un foreach pero no pude solucionarlo

```
decimal Porc = (Convert.ToDecimal(txtAumento.Text) / 100);
            string precioSinIva = DataPrecios.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            decimal NuevoPrecioSinIva = Convert.ToDecimal(precioSinIva)  + (Porc * Convert.ToDecimal(precioSinIva));
            DataPrecios.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value = Math.Round(NuevoPrecioSinIva, 2);

            //Calculamos el Iva en dinero
            decimal IvaEnDinero = NuevoPrecioSinIva * Convert.ToDecimal(0.08);
            DataPrecios.CurrentRow.Cells["IvaEnDinero"].Value = IvaEnDinero;

            //Precio Nuevo Total
            decimal NuevoPrecioFinal = NuevoPrecioSinIva + IvaEnDinero;
            DataPrecios.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value = Math.Round(NuevoPrecioFinal,2);

            //Proceso para M.U
            string Costo = DataPrecios.CurrentRow.Cells["Costo"].Value.ToString();

            if (Convert.ToDecimal(Costo) > 0)
            {
                decimal ValorCosto = NuevoPrecioSinIva / Convert.ToDecimal(Costo);
                if (ValorCosto > 1)
                {
                    ValorCosto -= 1;
                    double NuevoMU = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(ValorCosto) * 100, 2);
                    DataPrecios.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value = NuevoMU;
                }
            }
```

Comment: cuando hablas de celdas, querras decir filas? o sea, vos queres calcular esto para todas las filas?

Comment: Perdon si, de todas las filas

Comment: es en wpf? o en winforms? igual, si cambias CurrentRow por Rows[n] solucionas el problema... CurrentRow solo mira la fila que actual

Comment: Es en WinForms, podrias explicarme un poco mas?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows?view=netcore-3.1#remarks.. la propiedad Rows es un array de filas que podes recorrer con foreach...

Comment: Muchas gracias ya entendí, ya me funciono lo que necesitaba hacer